# WPF DataGrid SelectionChanged and button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid to which I bind some items.This grid has a  SelectionChanged event.and I have a button with Click event.The Problem is that when user click buton datagrid selectionchanged event also fired.

```
private void dgLogins_SelectionChanged(object sender,SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UserLoginEO objUserLogin = (UserLoginEO)dgLogins.SelectedItem;
        txtCodeKarbar.Text = objUserLogin.CodeKarbar.ToString();
        txtName.Text = objUserLogin.Name;
        txtFamily.Text = objUserLogin.Family;
        txtUserName.Text = objUserLogin.UserName;

    e.Handled = true;   
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,228,0,0"  Name="dgLogins" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObsUsers,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="dgLogins_SelectionChanged" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserId">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding  Path="CodeKarbar" Mode="TwoWay">
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding  Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay">
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Familt">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding  Path="Family" Mode="TwoWay">
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserName">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding  Path="UserName" Mode="TwoWay">
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can check **OriginalSource** property of **SelectionChangedEventArgs**, So you can check the event raised by which control, if it is from a button than ignore.

Answer (score 2):

I have an ugly way of doing it, but for me it works:

Here is my selection changed event:

```
private void DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;

    if (btnClicked)
    {
        if (e.RemovedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            dg.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged);
            var op1 = dg.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dg.SelectedIndex = -1),
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            op1.Completed += new EventHandler((s, ea) => dg.SelectionChanged +=
                new SelectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged));
        }
        else
        {
            dg.SelectionChanged -= new SelectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged);
            var op2 = dg.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dg.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0]),
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            op2.Completed += new EventHandler((s, ea) => dg.SelectionChanged +=
                new SelectionChangedEventHandler(DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged));
        }
        btnClicked = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

And the preview event of my button:

```
private bool btnClicked = false;
private void BtnTestSelection_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    btnClicked = true;
}
```

So, basically, if no selection is made before, we will keep it that way by setting SelectedIndex = -1. Otherwise, we return the selection to the previous one. In both cases, we remove the handler to avoid infinite calls and on OnCompleted we add it again.

If someone has en elegant way, maybe redefine the DataGrid in some way, i would be curious to see it and learn something useful.

Button's Click event didn't worked for me, but the tunneling one did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "Interactivity" assembly and `SelectionChanged` event.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Where "i" is namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

When some event fires activate every commaned you want while still keeping the princebles of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You use IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property in DataGrid. I think that it is reason of your issue. Try to disable the property or recode button click event handler.